# How do you actually call a nested function while extending modules in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I basically tried extending modules with two different modules

1st-

```
var exports=exports.module={};
exports.tutorial= function(){
    console.log('Raj is king');
};
```

2nd module

```
var tutor= require('./Tutorial.js');
exports.NodeTutorial= function(){
    console.log('Node Tutorial');
    function pTutor()
    {
        var putor=tutor;
        putor.tutorial();
    }

};
```

and finally tried to use these modules with a main.js file

```
var Addition= require('./NodeTutorial.js');
Addition.NodeTutorial();
Addition.NodeTutorial.pTutor();
```

However when I tried to execute the code i got the msg
`Type Error: Addition.NodeTutorial.pTutor is not a function`

Comment: Use `exports = function() {}` to export

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

`pTutor` is locally scoped to the function it is declared within. It is not accessible outside that function.

If you want it to be a property of that function, then you need to make it a property.

```
var tutor = require('./Tutorial.js');
exports.NodeTutorial = function() {
    console.log('Node Tutorial');
}
exports.NodeTutorial.pTutor = function pTutor() {
    var putor = tutor;
    putor.tutorial();
};
```

---

Note that while it is possible to attach properties to functions (jQuery does it so you can call, for example both `jQuery(...)` and `jQuery.ajax(...)`) it usually results in a confusing API and is best avoided.

Comment: arent you missing a semicolon at the end of the line export.NodeTutorial or is it just me and my lack of knowledge? And how do I call that method pTutor

Comment: [No, I'm not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) and *the way you were trying to do it in the question*